# Make OpenLayers request WMS tiles only within a certain bounds

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, wms, maps

Is there a way to actually tell OpenLayers not to request tiles out of particular bounds?

I want the rest of map and other layers still accessible, so maxExtent on map is not an option for me. I just want to restrict one WMS layer to particular bounds. If view port is inside the bounds and user zooms in fine, OpenLayers requests new tiles! but if viewport is outside, the WMS should only fill the bounded area with tiles from that WMS layer.

Does that make sense or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [maxExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.maxExtent) option on layer level.

Comment: I have already mentioned why i cant use maxExtent

Comment: You wrote `maxExtent on map` but I proposed to use maxExtent not on map but on layer level. maxExtent on map and on layer level are completely different options!

Comment: yup, I know, but even if WMS inherits from Layer, setting maxExtent on WMS layer, doesn't stop Openlayers from requesting tiles from out of bounds! If you have tried this option and its working for you, please let me know,becuase then something else ,might be wrong, although thats unlikely.

Comment: I've modified my own project. Comapre: http://demo.nextgis.ru/balakovo/gse.html (with maxExtent option) and http://demo.nextgis.ru/balakovo (original version).

Comment: you were right. maxExtent on layer does work. but only when tiling is enabled. If layer is set to single tile.. it ignores the maxExtent! thats silly! any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are bothered by pink, broken image tiles, you can change `.olOnImageLoadError` css class to `{ display: none; important! }`.

Comment: Nothing like that. I just want to restrict it.

Comment: Issue I am trying to address here is performance. I just dont need the tiles outside of bounds. The layer is vector intensive and WMS takes time to render it. Also Tile Cache is not an option as i am using dynamic SLDs everytime.

Comment: Then the other answer has the right suggestion for you i think.